# Unknown user name or bad password

Tags: windows-server-2003, security, oracle

I have 2 application hosted on server A which connects to the database server B. For every few seconds, there is this error log in the event viewer of the database sever.

Both window services started successfully on server A which explains no reason for the invalid user name or password.

Anyone have encounter such issues before?

```
Reason=Unknown user name or bad password&&User Name=<account name>&&Domain=<machine name>&&Logon Type=3&&Logon Process=NtLmSsp&&Authentication Package=NTLM&&Workstation Name=<machine name>&&Caller User Name=-&&Caller Domain=-&&Caller Logon ID=-&&Caller Process ID=-&&Transited Services=-&&Source Network Address=-&&Source Port=-&&User=SYSTEM&&ComputerName=<machine name>
```

Comment: Am I right in assuming this is MS SQL Server?

Comment: I am using Oracle as the database server.

Comment: Server A and Database Server B are both running on Window 2003 Server

Comment: Both window services in server A runs under a custom created user "user01" this user name appears in database server B event viewer.

Comment: could it be because the account used in Server A which does not exist in Database Server B which causes this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your sqlnet configuration, Oracle may try to authenticate users using Windows NT native authentication.

Check the content of files sqlnet.ora (look for "AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES") and read the related [Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14213/sqlnet.htm#sthref443)

Comment: what is the purpose of AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES. I should be updating this value at the client or server side?

Comment: Which part of the documentation don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

do you have any network monitors running that could be issuing port checks for specific services?  sometimes when that network socket is opened, you can trigger an authentication error log event, even though there wasn't actually a bad login.

Comment: no network monitoring